# Nextflow filter entire tuple based on one value

Tags: filter, tuples, nextflow

Needing some extra guidance on filtering an entire tuple based on one value.

I have a channel of tuples (reads_ch):

```
[[id:S1, single_end:false], [/home/ubuntu/S1.R1.fastq.gz, /home/ubuntu/S1.R2.fastq.gz], /home/ubuntu/S1.txt, [PASSED: File S1_R1 is not corrupt., PASSED: File S1_R2 is not corrupt.]]
[[id:S2, single_end:false], [/home/ubuntu/S2.fastq.gz, /home/ubuntu/S2.R2.fastq.gz], /home/ubuntu/S2.txt, [PASSED: File S2_R1 is not corrupt., PASSED: File S2_R2 is not corrupt.]]
[[id:S3, single_end:false], [/home/ubuntu/S3.R1.fastq.gz, /home/ubuntu/S3.R2.fastq.gz], /home/ubuntu/S3.txt, [FAILED, FAILED]]
```

I am trying to filter this for any sample that did not 'fail'. I've gotten as far as clearing it[3] but haven't figured out how to remove that sample. while keeping the structure of the remaining samples (S1,S2)

Goal:

```
[[id:S1, single_end:false], [/home/ubuntu/S1.R1.fastq.gz, /home/ubuntu/S1.R2.fastq.gz], /home/ubuntu/S1.txt, [PASSED: File S1_R1 is not corrupt., PASSED: File S1_R2 is not corrupt.]]
[[id:S2, single_end:false], [/home/ubuntu/S2.fastq.gz, /home/ubuntu/S2.R2.fastq.gz], /home/ubuntu/S2.txt, [PASSED: File S2_R1 is not corrupt., PASSED: File S2_R2 is not corrupt.]]
```

Attempt:

```
passing = read_ch.map { meta, reads, outcome_file, outcome_status ->
tuple(meta, reads, outcome_file, outcome_status.findAll { !it.contains('FAILED') })
}
passing.view()

[[id:S1, single_end:false], [/home/ubuntu/S1.R1.fastq.gz, /home/ubuntu/S1.R2.fastq.gz], /home/ubuntu/S1.txt, [PASSED: File S1_R1 is not corrupt., PASSED: File S1_R2 is not corrupt.]]
[[id:S2, single_end:false], [/home/ubuntu/S2.fastq.gz, /home/ubuntu/S2.R2.fastq.gz], /home/ubuntu/S2.txt, [PASSED: File S2_R1 is not corrupt., PASSED: File S2_R2 is not corrupt.]]
[[id:S3, single_end:false], [/home/ubuntu/S3.R1.fastq.gz, /home/ubuntu/S3.R2.fastq.gz], /home/ubuntu/S3.txt, []]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire channel element is supposed to be removed even if only one sample failed? If that's what you want, you'll find the solution below:

Preparing a fake channel similar to yours:

```
Channel
  .of([
        [id:'S1', single_end:false],
        [file('/home/ubuntu/S1.R1.fastq.gz'), file('/home/ubuntu/S1.R2.fastq.gz')],
        file('/home/ubuntu/S1.txt'),
        ['PASSED: File S1_R1 is not corrupt.', 'PASSED: File S1_R2 is not corrupt.']
      ],
      [
        [id:'S2', single_end:false],
        [file('/home/ubuntu/S2.fastq.gz'), file('/home/ubuntu/S2.R2.fastq.gz')],
        file('/home/ubuntu/S2.txt'),
        ['PASSED: File S2_R1 is not corrupt.', 'PASSED: File S2_R2 is not corrupt.']
      ],
      [
        [id:'S3', single_end:false],
        [file('/home/ubuntu/S3.R1.fastq.gz'), file('/home/ubuntu/S3.R2.fastq.gz')],
        file('/home/ubuntu/S3.txt'),
        ['FAILED', 'FAILED']
      ])
  .set { my_ch }
```

Filtering:

```
my_ch
  .filter { it[3].findAll { !it.contains('FAILED') } }
  .view()
```

Output:

[image]

You can also do it like this:

```
my_ch
  .filter { it[3][0] != 'FAILED' && it[3][1] != 'FAILED' }
  .view()
```

which makes it easy to adapt if you want either of one failing, instead of both.

Comment: YES YES YES! This is exactly what I was looking for.

and even more YES for the second example, filtering it by either of the two it[3] locations. Is there a way to make this even more flexible to do a ~= (contains) 'FAILED' rather than being "!=" (not equal)? I'm thinking of a scenario where we write additional info "FAILED DUE TO X" in which case it wouldnt do the filtering as we expect.

Either way, THANK YOU

Comment: The first solution with `contains` already does that. As for the second, you can do `.filter { !it[3][0].contains('FAILED') && !it[3][1].contains('FAILED') }`